# Crossbow Expert feat second clause clarification

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, ranged-attack

The Crossbow Expert Feat has three clauses:

> Thanks to extensive practice with the crossbow, you
>   gain the fol lowing benefits:
>
> • You ignore the loading quality of crossbows with which you are proficient.
>
> • Being withing 5 feet of a hostile creature doesn't impose disadvantage on your ranged attack rolls.
>
> • When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a loaded hand crossbow you are holding.

I'm looking at the second clause in particular:

> Being withing 5 feet of a hostile creature doesn't impose disadvantage on your ranged attack rolls.

Note that it doesn't say "Being withing 5 feet of a hostile creature doesn't impose disadvantage on your ranged attack roles ***that you make with a crossbow***."

That being said, does this clause only apply to ranged attack roles that you make with a crossbow? I would assume so, but why doesn't it say it?